# Label component is not recognized by Visual Studio's Form Designer

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I develop small labwork project in C++/CLR with WinForms UI. So, when I add any label on my form, Form Designer shows the following error:

```
 C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 185, Column: 17 --- Unknown type ''. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.
```

Call stack:

```
in Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
in System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

There is definition and initialisation of all the form controls:

```
  //Definition
private: RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
private: Button^  button1;
private: Button^  button2;
private: Button^  button3;
private: Button^  button4;
private: TextBox^  textBox1;
private: Button^  button5;
private: Button^  button6;
private: Button^  button7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;

  //Initialisation
        this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
```

When I'm trying to change namespace of the `Label` in the definition, Form Designer shows me another error:

```
   C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 298, Column: 27 --- Member AutoSize not found in class System.Reflection.Emit.Label
```

As I can see, it doesn't recognize `Label` as `System::Windows::Forms` component and hence won't render my form. Any operations with namespaces in initialisations and definitions don't help. Most interesting part is that project compiles successfully.

So, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Editing the designer-generated code yourself is a Bad Idea.  The CodeDOM parser is not a full-blown C++ parser and can only ever properly read code that it generated itself.  Clearly it did not generate private: Button^  button7, you wrote or edited that by hand.  Your snippet does not otherwise produce an error so it is just random guessing.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes. I've delete namespaces from other components, because CodeDOM throwed me the same error on another components. In this file was already a directive ‘using namespace System::Windows:: Forms‘, so I decided to remove it from components as unnecessary. And Form Designer opens my form.